# Parsing 802.11 action no ack frames

Tags: parsing, wireshark, wifi

I'm looking for documentation on how to parse 802.11 Action No Ack Management frames (Subtype 0d14), but I haven't found anything useful. Specifically I'm looking for a list of possible fixed parameters and their sizes.

Where can I find documentation that will tell me this information?

Looking at these packets in Wireshark, they all seem to only have one fixed parameter, VHT. However, just looking at my sample data does not convince me that's all that can appear there, or that it always will appear there.

Comment: If you mean that the frame control field is 0d14, then the subtype is Action (d), not ActionNoAck (e).

Comment: ... or, seeing how the bit-order is unclear to me, perhaps it is Authentication (b).

Comment: No, I mean specifically the subtype nybble only. So the whole frame control field is 0xE000 as it appears in the data, but specifically the four bites representing the subtype are 0b1110.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, these are defined in wifi spec like "IEEE Std 802.11™-2016"
You can still find out the definition from other wifi document, e.g. 
wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.11_Frame_Types

Action No Ack frame is the action frame which doesn't need Ack.
e.g. Link Measurement Request frame can be a kind of Action frame, or Action No Ack frame

https://njiot.blogspot.com/2019/08/wifi-action-no-ack.html